# (PyQT4) Python instantly closes after launch

Tags: python, macos, pyqt4

I am very new to PyQTt, I am working on Mac OS X, so i have installed PyQtX which works without any problems when importing PyQt4.

So i just tried making a very simple application:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QtGui.QWidget()

window.show()

window.raise_()
```

When launching this with Python2, Python application shows in dock and instantly closes (Without showing any result).

Is it because i'm missing something on my system? What can a problem be?

Comment: Replace the last line with `app.exec_()` (i.e. start the event-loop).

Comment: Thanks! worked without any problems.